# read the name of all files in a given directory and find the pattern using SAS

Tags: sas

I have the following task in SAS. Ggiven is an Excel file which I imported in SAS. In one column "looking_date" a date occurs I am interested in.

[image]

From the other hand there is a directory ("C:\myWork\") containing many files. 
[image]

The name of every file in this directory contains a date and another part which could be always different.

SO I try it in a algorithm form:

1. look for every date in column "looking_date"
2. check in directory "C:\myWork\"  (kind of pattern matching) if the date from "looking_date" occurs in the name of one file then import
   the file with giving the date as the name

I have no idea how can I implement both steps above. At first I thought I read the name of all files from this directory, however I have still the problem with pattern the name!
I am grateful for every hint just to be able to begin

Comment: Your requirement for pattern checking is not clear. Also please post what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

To read a directory on the operating system you can use `data step` like this:

```
%let path_to_catalog=C:\myWork;

data files;
    /* define a directory */
    rc = filename("mydir","&path.");
    /* open the directory */
    did = dopen("mydir");
    /* check if it's opened */
    if did > 0 then do;
        /* itereate over objects in the directory */
        do n = 1 to dnum(did);
            /* read name of file */
            filename = dread(did, n);
            /* output files with *.DAT extension */
            if scan(upcase(filename), -1, '.') = 'DAT' then 
                output;
        end;
    end;
    /* close the directory */
    rc = dclose(did);

    drop rc did;
run;
```

read dates from an excel file

```
libname exc_lib pcfiles "path_to_execel";
proc sql;
    select distinct input(looking_date, ddmmyy8.)
    into :dates separated by ','
    from exc_lib.'sheet1$'n;
quit;
```

check if a file contains date from an excel file

```
data result;
    set files;
    date = input(substr(filename, 1, 8), ddmmyy8.);
    if date in (&dates) then output;
run;
```

Comment: Why do I get from the first part an empty table.  the only difference is:  %let path_to_catalog=\\vol1\statist_prod\Datenbank_ZIK\Archiv;

data files;
    /* define a directory */
    rc = filename("Archiv","&\\vol1\statist_prod\Datenbank_ZIK\");
    /* open the directory */
    did = dopen("Archiv");
    /* check if it's opened */

Comment: type your path only in `%let` statement e.g. `%let path_to_catalog=\\vol1\statist_prod\Datenbank_ZIK;`

Comment: Robert, I did it however I get an empty table, then I checked the part without 'if did > 0' the code is not going into the loop. That is the problem I guess. How can I check if it looks in the correct path?

Comment: I tried:    %let path_to_catalog=\\ftai06\vol1\statist_prod\Datenbank_ZIK\Archiv;

data files;
    /* define a directory */
    rc = filename("mydir","&path.");
    /* open the directory */
    did = dopen("mydir");
    /* check if it's opened */
    test=did;
    /* close the directory */
    rc = dclose(did);

    drop rc did;
run; 
the result is 'did'=0